# Android: CalendarProvider events not created and sometimes disappears after created(in few devices)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-calendar

I am creating calendar event programmatically(Android platform).

Following is my piece of code:
Here User has right to select plan *date(`planDate.value`)*, *start time(`planStartTime.value`)*, *end time(`planEndTime.value`)* and enter plan *name(`planName.value`)*

```
private fun createCalendarEvent(context: Context) {
        val startDateObj = SimpleDateFormat(simpleDateFormateMM, Locale.US).parse("${planDate.value} ${planStartTime.value}") // Here I am fetching data selected by user
        val endDateObj = SimpleDateFormat(simpleDateFormateMM, Locale.US).parse("${planDate.value} ${planEndTime.value}")

        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.time = startDateObj

        val startMillis: Long = Calendar.getInstance().run {
            // month starts from 0
            set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
            timeInMillis
        }
        calendar.time = endDateObj
        val endMillis: Long = Calendar.getInstance().run {
            set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
            timeInMillis
        }

        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis)
            put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 3)
            } else {
                put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1)
            }
            put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, planName.value)
            put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().id)
        }
        if (!PermissionUtils(context).checkPermission(PermissionUtils.WRITE_CALENDAR)) {
            context.contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values)
        }
    }
```

When I am trying to create an event, in few devices, events are created successfully and stays.

But in few devices(eg. Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime) events are not created at all. The device in which events are not created, I am getting eventID after insert method.

```
var eventUri: Uri = context.contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values)
```

In `Huawei CAG-L22`, event is created but after few seconds, it disappears from the calendar.

I am using the same code for all these devices.

Can anyone help me with this? Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Thank you in advance.